# Gatsby: combining two graphql sources on a page (.json and .jpg sources)

Tags: json, graphql, gatsby

## context

I am turning an old php ecommerce site into a static site built with gatsby.js.

I put all my product metadata into separate .json files (one per product) and I am able to load them with json and file transformer plugins. They are in `/items`.  However each item is related to a set of standard images... eg `item-01-main.jpg`, `item-01-placement.jpg`, etc... I put all the images together in `/itemphotos`and followed the instructions here to load them into graphql: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/

## question

On the page that loads all the products, i have no idea how to incorporate each one's `item-xx-main.jpg` image: **I don't know what graphql query would fetch BOTH sets of data and match/merge them.**:

```
/items
  item-01.json
  item-02.json
/itemphotos
  item-01-main.jpg
  item-01-placement.jpg
  item-02-main.jpg
  item-02-placement.jpg
```

I have a feeling my directory structure was the wrong approach and maybe I should store all the related images with my product json together in a folder:

```
/items
  item-01/
    item-01.json
    item-01-main.jpg
    item-01-placement.jpg
  item-02/
    item-02.json
    item-02-main.jpg
    item-02-placement.jpg
```

But then **how do I source an `items/` directory made up of `item-xx/` subfolders holding both images and json, as representing a single entity, in graphql**?

I did not go with markdown files because I wanted max UI flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Structure 2

Can you reference your images inside the `.json`? If so, the 2nd structure could be the winner, since you won't have to do much extra work:

```
// item-01.json

{
  "meta": "...",
  "main": "./item-01-main.jpg",
  "placement": "./item-01-placement.jpg"
}
```

Query:

```
{
  json {
    id
    main {
      childImageSharp {
        fixed {
          src
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Structure 1

If that's not possible or if you'd like to keep the 1st structure, you can try this query:

```
{
  item: allFile(filter: { relativePath: { regex: "/item-01/" } }) {
    nodes {
      name
      extension
      children {
        ... on ImageSharp {
          fixed {
            src
          }
        }
        ... on Item01Json {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will yield an array containing all files that share the same item id, regardless where they are stored. You can then use `extension` field to find the `json` & `jpg` nodes. It's not pretty, but it also doesn't require that much additional work.

---

### None of the above

If none of that works for you, you could explore adding a image field to the json's graphql schema with [`createTypes` and `createResolvers`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-03-18-releasing-new-schema-customization/).  Add a type definition for the json via `createTypes`, then use `createResolvers` to locate the `imageSharp` node & resolve it.

Comment: oh wow... I'm really liking your structure 2 response!!! I haven't had a chance to try it yet... I expect to select this answer soon enough tho!

Comment: ok finally tried this out... it works! I got a bit further with `allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "products"} })` since i wanted to pull all products.. thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

A more clear cut example can be found from their code repo [this page](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-contentful/src/pages/index.js#L83-L114). This uses the same method as @Derek discussed. But if you want an example to understand more.